# Introducing a delay using timers in Arduino

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

I'm doing register level programming in Arduino. The goal is to write my own delay logic using timers. Here is the code:

```
#include<avr/io.h>

int main()
{
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB5);
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS12);
    while(1)
    {
        if(TCNT1 >= 31250)
        {
            PORTB ^= (1<<PORTB5);
            TCNT1 = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program is for Arduino to introduce a delay without using the delay function and its working all right. But have a look at the code below.

```
#include<avr/io.h>

void setup()
{
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB5);
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS12);
}

void loop()
{
    if(TCNT1 >= 31250)
    {
        PORTB ^= (1<<PORTB5);
        TCNT1 = 0;
    }
}
```

When I write it this way, the program is getting compiled but there is no blinking in Arduino. What might be the problem while the code below which is similar to the above code is working fine?

```
#include <util/delay.h>

void setup()
{
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB5);
}

void loop()
{
    PORTB ^= (1<<PORTB5);
    _delay_ms(500);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like C, especially with the `#include <avr/io.h>` at the top and the use of a `main()` function.  Are you compiling this with avr-gcc/AVRstudio or do you intend to write a sketch with the Arduino IDE?

Assuming that you're trying to write C, your latter file is written more for the Arduino IDE which implicitly includes a `main()` function which does something like:

```
int main()
{
  setup();
  while(1) {
    loop();
  }
}
```

which appears to be the environment that your latter code sample expects.  Try adding the above `main()` function at the bottom of the second file (after the `setup()` and `loop()` functions are defined).  If you want to have main() at the top, you'll need to *declare* your functions with a function prototype before you define them.   Or, better yet, move your latter code sample to its own file and give it a header:

### main.c

```
#include "blink.h"

int main(void)
{
  blink_setup();
  while(1) {
    blink_loop();
  }
}
```

### blink.h

```
#ifndef BLINK_H  // Include guards prevent this file from being duplicated
#define BLINK_H

void blink_setup(void);  // blink_ prefix allows other modules to use comm
void blink_loop(void);

#endif
```

The #ifndef ... #define ... #endif structure, known as include guards, prevents errors if this file is included multiple times in a compilation, which can happen easily if other `.h` files refer to it.  The `blink_` prefix is useful because `setup()` and `loop()` are common names and might be used by other modules.  If you're familiar with other OO languages, this would be similar to the concept of a namespace or class prefix.

### blink.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "blink.h"

void setup()
{
   DDRB = ( 1 << PORTB5 );
   TCCR1B = ( 1 << CS12 );
}

void loop()
{
   if( TCNT1 >= 31250 )
   {
      PORTB ^= ( 1 << PORTB5 );
      TCNT1 = 0;
   }
}
```

Notice that I've included blink.h at the top of this file, using the `"` quote marks instead of brackets because it's a local file not a system file.  This causes the function declarations to appear at the top of the file, so that (for example) `setup()` could call `loop()` even though it's not been defined yet.

Other than that environment problem, your code looks like it ought to work.  I prefer a little more whitespace; I've added it in my code samples, but other than that everything looks great!

Comment: Thank you,I'm using arduino IDE for all the codes in the question.Adding main() below setup() and loop() functions and calling them solved my problem.But i have a doubt.I'm editing my question to reflect the same.Check out the qstn once again plzz...thnx once again :)